# Free or very cheap software for Windows that would allow me to demo an web application with smooth cursor movement

Tags: windows, automation, screen-recording

I need to create a video demo of my company's web application. Camtasia offers a [feature](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UIMZ60-u0bM) that will "smooth" out the cursor movements in a screen recording. However, Camtasia is quite expensive, and I do not foresee using it often enough to justify expensing it.

I would like a free or very cheap piece of software for Windows that would allow me to achieve a similar professional effect. There are a few ways I could imagine this implemented:

- An integrated screen recording software like Camtasia, with an automatic cursor smoothing feature.
- Software for Windows that allows me to define the cursor's path and actions ahead of time. I could then do the actual recording with OBS.
- The above, but as a Chrome or Firefox extension.

Other nice features could include:

- Editing cursor paths as splines.
- Pre-defining or smoothing out keyboard input as well.

I realize I could achieve a similar effect programmatically with AutoHotkey or Python, but I think a GUI based software package would be more suitable for this sort of one-off use case.

Does such an application exist?

Answer (score 0):

I've found [a tutorial page](https://allthings.how/enable-mouse-smoothing-windows-draw-lines-any-software/) for Windows tools that smooth out cursor movements, but your actual cursor motion is smoothed out (it doesn't just appear smooth in a screen recording). One of the programs is called SilkyShark. It's not precisely what you asked for, but I hope this helps